# What is the closest equivalent to the English "good to go"?

Tags: translation, idioms, english-comparison

I've seen a couple of different variations in some reverse-translations:

- pronto a partire
- pronto ad andare
- pronto (seems like this is just "ready" though)
- buono per andare

Most of these seem like they're highly specific or too literal to whatever particular usage of "good to go" was being translated. Is there a go-to Italian version of this?

---

For those who aren't familiar with the expression, being "good to go" indicates the readiness of a person or thing with an emphasis on the fact that the person / thing may not have been ready before (if that's not true, then it's synonymous with being ready).

So, if a toaster was broken, and then got fixed by someone, the repairman could say "it's good to go". To say "it's ready" while correct, to me would sound a little odd.

For a person, it could be that you were getting dressed and weren't ready to leave, and now you're ready to leave so you could say "I'm good to go." The more-general: "I'm ready." would work in this case, but it's technically a little ambiguous -- what are you ready for?

Comment: Since this is a site about Italian, not everybody is necessarily conversant with AE idioms. Could you spend some words about the meaning of “good to go”? Is the definition “ready or prepared for something” correct?

Comment: @DaG Just added an explanation. It's more about something being ready, that originally wasn't. In everyday speech, it is increasingly used as a direct synonym for being ready, but I'm more asking about the first definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a toaster you could say

> **È a posto, può andare**

meaning it’s ready to go into operation again.

For a person you could say

> **Pronto a partire**

or simply

> **pronto**

meaning you’re ready to leave or simply you’re ready to do the thing you’re about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @abarisone. I imagine, if plural, then for the toasters analogy it would be: "Sono a posto, possono andare.", and with the second statement: "Pronti/e a partire."?

Comment: Exactly, using the plural form

Comment: @Marco, just notice that Italian *partire* is more restricted semantically than English “to leave”. You *parti* for a journey or a holiday, but not simply to say that you are, say, simply going out of your home for some errand or a night out.

Comment: @DaG, Got it! So I guess for the latter situations you describe, the correct phrase would be "Pronto/a/i/e a andare." or is there another alternative?